# How to do the convolution of a normal distribution with a truncated exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have a random variable $A$ with $A = B + C$, where $B$ is a normal distribution with the usual range $(-\infty , +\infty)$ and $C$ is a truncated exponential distribution of range $(a,b)$. How to obtain the probability distribution of $A$?

Comment: Before continuing further, you should specify what parameterisations you a are assuming: e.g. whether your Normal distribution is standard Normal, or $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, what functional form you are using for your Exponential, and whether it is standard Exponential, or with a parameter (rate or mean).

Comment: Both of them are in their standard forms, i.e. $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\frac{1} {(e^{-a/\lambda}-e^{-b/\lambda})}. \frac{1} {\lambda}.e^{-x/\lambda}$.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I am more or less sure about the solution, but not 100%. It shall be helpful if someone verifies the same. Tha answer that I've obtained is: $f_{A}(a)=\frac{e^{\frac{\sigma^2} {2\lambda^2}}} {\lambda (e^{-a/\lambda}-e^{-b/\lambda})}.e^{-y/\lambda}.[Q(\frac{a+\frac{\sigma^2} {\lambda}-a} {\sigma})-Q(\frac{b+\frac{\sigma^2} {\lambda}-a} {\sigma})]$ and range of $f_{A}(a)$ is $(-\infty , +\infty)$.

Comment: $Q$ symbol used above is the standard well known $Q$ function, i.e. $Q(x)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{u^2} {2}} du$

Comment: Mr Mukherjee ... would you not reasonably expect your solution to depend on $\mu$? Yet your proposed answer (stated without derivation) does not.

Comment: Mr Mukherjee ... I should also comment on your notation which appears confusing. You have a random variable $A$, a pdf $f(a)$ which refers to the random variable $A$, and a parameter $a$ that is the lower bound on the truncated exponential. One of these needs a new nomenclature.

Comment: I'm really sorry for mixing the things, though it was not an intentional one. In my context, $B$ follows $N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $C$ follows truncated exponential distribution in the range $(p,q)$, i.e. $C$ follows $\frac{1} {e^{-p/\lambda}-e^{-q/\lambda}}.\frac{1} {\lambda}.e^{-c/\lambda}$. Hence the obtained solution is: $f_{A}(a)$=$\frac{e^{\frac{\sigma^2} {2\lambda^2}}} {\lambda(e^{-p/\lambda}-e^{-q/\lambda})}.e^{-a/\lambda}.[Q(\frac{p+\frac{\sigma^2} {\lambda}-a} {\sigma})-Q(\frac{q+\frac{\sigma^2} {\lambda}-a} {\sigma})]$ and the range of $f_{A}$(a) is $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: Mr Mukherjee, the difficulty lies in the linkage between knowing the pdf of B and pdf of C ... and then your statement: `"Hence, the obtained solution is ..."`. The stated solution appears incorrect to me, but in the absence of any workings, that is just an impression.

Comment: @wolfies, if you can be a more technical...then it shall be helpful. As for the problem, I have just convoluted the two pdfs of $B$ and $C$ to obtain the pdf of $A$ (that's the very definition of adding two random variables).

Comment: As I say, in the absence of any workings, there is not much to discuss.